# Excel: dropdown list determines how many rows are in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I am trying to populate rows based on user selection from a dropdown box.

When A3 is selected I would like to have column B populate (inserting the same number of rows + (the total row) as items in LIST2).

When A3 is changed the rows should be deleted and new rows should be updated as per LIST2.

The green cells:

- LIST1 - A3 is a named list
- LIST2 - B3:B12 is a named list dependent on A3

Expense sheet:

[image: expense sheet]

Comment: A screenshot of your spreadsheet would help to visualize what you're trying to do, but it sounds like a Pivot Table might be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did attach a screen shot called expense sheet which is the link at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Seth,, you need to create Dependant Drop down !

Comment: @Seth,, Can you upload Sample data will help me to create method to justify my answer!!

Comment: Hi Raj, I already have the dependant lists working. Col-A shows 1 from a category list... Income, Household, Financial etc... As can be observed in Col-B a second dependant list is displayed, in this case 'Household' as each of the Col-A list has different amounts of items in the the sublist I wanted to have coding that determined how many items were in the sublist  and added that number of rows and populated them from the sublist AND inserted the formula to calculate the monthly values.